# How to POST the ID of an HTML Element

Tags: php, html

I'm setting up a web-based employee overview and I want to update / delete the employees through the website.

I get my data out of my database and put it into a table.
I want to POST the ID of the HTML Element to get the context.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo
   "
   <tr>
    <td>{$row['Vorname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Nachname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['farbe']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
    <form action='Ma_bear.php' method='post'>
    <td>
    <input type='submit' name='test' value='Bearbeiten' id={$row['Mitarbeiterid']} />
    <input type='submit' name='test2' value='Löschen' id={$row['Mitarbeiterid']} />
    </td>
    </tr>\n
    </form>";
}
```

And the other End:

```
<?php echo $_POST["test"]; ?>
```

With this code the output is: "Bearbeiten", but I want it to be the ID of the Element.

Is there a way to do this in php? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: if you are looking for better way to do this, I suggest you look into any PHP ORM. I recommend fat-free framework though because it is very beginner friendly. you should be able to code the whole application very fast with fat-free framework.

Comment: Use a `button` instead of `input type=submit` - that one allows you to specify a submission value different from the button content it shows. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: And that nesting of a `form` element into a `tr` at this point is invalid. The form needs to either go around the whole table (in that case, the currently accepted answer won’t work), or it needs to be contained in a single table _cell_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This outputs `Bearbeiten` because this is the *value* of that input.

The `id` attribute is used for frontend purpose and won't be send automatically to the backend

Since both submit buttons should post the same value, you can use a 3rd input, hidden, to pass this data.

In example :

```
<form action='Ma_bear.php' method='post'>
    <!--
                   |            |                 |
                   V            V                 V             -->
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value={$row['Mitarbeiterid']} />
    <input type='submit' name='test' value='Bearbeiten' />
    <input type='submit' name='test2' value='Löschen' />
</form>
```

In the above example, the `name` of the input is `id`. This is of course an **arbitrary** name, you can name it as you want.

And get it using `$_POST['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write:

```html
<input type='hidden' name='Mitarbeiterid' value='{$row['Mitarbeiterid']'}/>
```

So each time you send a form, the value Mitarbeiterid will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use input buttons, but *button* buttons

```
<button name="edit" value="123">Edit</button>
<button name="delete" value="123">Delete</button>
```

This will either send `edit:123` or `delete:123` as POST values